# Closed generics in .NET XML comments

Tags: .net, xml-comments

If i have the following function:

```
void ReadData(Action<DataContext> action) {}
```

how can i reference it in `seealso` construct?

```
<seealso cref="ReadData(Action<DataContext>)"/>
```

complains "The character '<' cannot be used in an attribute value". Changing '<' and '>' to '{' and '}' works but makes it open generic parameter.

Comment: Maybe by using the entity representations `&lt;` and `&gt;`?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "makes it open generic parameter"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<seealso cref="ReadData(Action{DataContext})"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

From section A.3.1 of the C# 4 spec:

> - Arguments that use generic type parameters defined on types are encoded using the backtick character followed by the zero-based index of the type parameter.
> - Arguments that use generic type parameters defined in methods use a double-backtick instead of the single backtick used for types.
> - Arguments that refer to constructed generic types are encoded using the generic type, followed by "{", followed by a comma-separated list of type arguments, followed by "}".

(I've written backtick explicitly rather than including the character due to markdown limitations.)

Of these, the last bullet point is what you're after, so `Action{DataContext}` as per Petar's answer. I only included this answer for extra reference, basically :)